# In spark how to use window spec with aggregate functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark data frame that looks like:

```
+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|parent_key  |id       |value                                                       |raw_is_active           |updated_at         |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
|1           |2        |[, 0, USER, 2020-12-11 04:50:40, 2020-12-11 04:50:40,]      |[2020-12-11 04:50:40, 0]|2020-12-11 04:50:40|
|1           |2        |[testA, 0, USER, 2020-12-11 04:50:40, 2020-12-11 17:18:00,] |null                    |2020-12-11 17:18:00|
|1           |2        |[testA, 0, USER, 2020-12-11 04:50:40, 2020-12-11 17:19:56,] |null                    |2020-12-11 17:19:56|
|1           |2        |[testA, 1, USER, 2020-12-11 04:50:40, 2020-12-11 17:20:24,] |[2020-12-11 17:20:24, 1]|2020-12-11 17:20:24|
|2           |3        |[testB, 0, USER, 2020-12-11 17:24:03, 2020-12-11 17:24:03,] |[2020-12-11 17:24:03, 0]|2020-12-11 17:24:03|
|3           |4        |[testC, 0, USER, 2020-12-11 17:27:36, 2020-12-11 17:27:36,] |[2020-12-11 17:27:36, 0]|2020-12-11 17:27:36|
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
```

Schema is:

```
root
 |-- parent_key: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- is_active: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- updated_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- raw_is_active: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- updated_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- updated_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I am looking for an output:

```
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|parent_key  |id       |value                                                       |raw_is_active                                      |updated_at         |
+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|1           |2        |[testA, 1, USER, 2020-12-11 04:50:40, 2020-12-11 17:20:24]  |[[2020-12-11 04:50:40, 0],[2020-12-11 17:20:24, 1]]|2020-12-11 04:50:40|
|2           |3        |[testB, 0, USER, 2020-12-11 17:24:03, 2020-12-11 17:24:03]  |[2020-12-11 17:24:03, 0]                           |2020-12-11 17:24:03|
|3           |4        |[testC, 0, USER, 2020-12-11 17:27:36, 2020-12-11 17:27:36]  |[2020-12-11 17:27:36, 0]                           |2020-12-11 17:27:36|
+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

So on the basis of the `updated_at` column I want to keep the latest row and also wants to create an array for `raw_is_active` for all the rows for a given `id`.

I know I can pick the latest `value` using code:

```
 val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("updated_at").desc)

    dataFrame
      .withColumn("maxTS", first("updated_at").over(windowSpec))
      .select("*").where(col("maxTS") === col("updated_at"))
      .drop("maxTS")
```

**But not sure how I can also create a set for `raw_is_active` column.**

Or I can completely use group by function like:

```
 dataFrame
      .groupBy("parent_key", "id")
      .agg(collect_list("value") as "value_list", collect_set("raw_is_active") as "active_list")
      .withColumn("value", col("value_list")(size(col("value_list")).minus(1)))
      .drop("value_list")
```

For the above I am not sure

1. `.withColumn("value", col("value_list")(size(col("value_list")).minus(1)))` will always give me the latest value
2. Considering use of `collect_list` and `collect_set`, is this code efficient?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @mck, I was able to get it working with code:

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("updated_at").desc)
val windowSpecSet = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("updated_at"))

val df2 = dataFrame.withColumn(
    "rn",
    row_number().over(windowSpec)
).withColumn(
    "active_list",
    collect_set("raw_is_active").over(windowSpecSet)
).drop("raw_is_active").filter("rn = 1")
```

However the code is taking more time than my existing code:

```
 dataFrame
      .groupBy("parent_key", "id")
      .agg(collect_list("value") as "value_list", collect_set("raw_is_active") as "active_list")
      .withColumn("value", col("value_list")(size(col("value_list")).minus(1)))
      .drop("value_list")
```

I was under impression that window function would perform better than `groupBy` and `agg`.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a `row_number` for each row in each id partition and filter the rows with `row_number = 1`:

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("updated_at").desc)

val df2 = dataFrame.withColumn(
    "rn",
    row_number().over(windowSpec)
).withColumn(
    "active_list",
    array_sort(collect_set("raw_is_active").over(windowSpec))
).drop("raw_is_active").filter("rn = 1")
```

Comment: thanks for the help. The code is not working for me. While the latest `value` column is coming at rn= 1 the set of `active_list` is coming at the max(rn)

Comment: I was able to get it working by using two specs. Updated my question description.

Comment: `collect_set` does not guarantee order, regardless of how you specify the window. In this small case it just happens to be in a certain order because you're not executing on a cluster. If you need them in a certain order, use `array_sort`. See the docs at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_set-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-

Comment: this method may be a bit slower than your method, but it consumes less memory because it doesn't require the storage of all `value` in a list. If there are lots of `value`, you may hit memory errors in spark.

Comment: issue is not with order of the collection. The collection is set at `rn = 4` instead of `rn = 1`. To get this working have to use another WindowSpec which might be causing the performance issue. Looking for a way to get this done by using a single Spec

Comment: @JDev oh, I see what you mean, sorry for being confused. yes that may be the source of slowness, but it may be more memory efficient I guess..